# Disable the retake, play and use video screen UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am just wanting one screeen:
[image]
When using the `UIImagePickerController` it uses two screens.

But I don't want this one:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Fahri` is right `AVFoundation` is more flexible but if you want to stick with `UIImagePickerController` what you could do is turn off the camera control by setting `showsCameraControls` property to `NO`, then present your own view and custom methods.

Change your code to:

**takeVideo**

```
- (IBAction)takeVideo:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-54, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];

    toolBar.barStyle =  UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel  target:self action:@selector(cancelVideo)],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera  target:self action:@selector(shootVideo)],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil action:nil],
                    nil];
    [toolBar setItems:items];

    // create the overlay view
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
    overlayView.opaque=NO;
    overlayView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // parent view for our overlay
    UIView *cameraView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [cameraView addSubview:overlayView];
    [cameraView addSubview:toolBar];

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Camera not available");
        return;
    }

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    picker.delegate = self;

    // hide the camera controls
    picker.showsCameraControls=NO;
    [picker setCameraOverlayView:cameraView];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**shootVideo**

```
-(void) shootVideo {
    [picker startVideoCapture];
}
```

**cancelVideo**

```
- (IBAction)cancelVideo {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**screenshot**

[image]

<kbd>[**DOWNLOAD DEMO PROJECT**](https://mega.co.nz/#!2JgijIZT!mvDDeJIdUHRNWgmzn0k2A1GMcx0YCNtlUMk1KaJv_kA)</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot about this :) This could be faster way of achieving your task, @Maximilian.

Comment: Hey @meda I am having a problem with the 'picker' what do I need to put in the header file sorry?

Comment: @Maximilian you have to declare it on the class level, see my edit I included a demo  project for you to download

Comment: how do you handle the 'FinishedPickingMedia' ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already checked the documentation of `UIImagePickerController` before posting your question, then you can use `AVFoundation` library to build your own camera controller, with any controls and screens you want. Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry I thought there might be a nice easy way to do this.