# Automatically 'Use Photo' in Swift's UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, I launch the camera so they can take a photo. Once they hit the shutter button, they are by default taken to the next screen where they can 'Retake' or 'Use Photo'.

Can I eliminate this step, and just force them to use that photo?

Thank you in advance )

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is not an easy way to achieve this, you have to hide all camera controls and create custom controls. You will use:

`imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
 imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = yourCustomOverlayView`

Please find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427545/disable-the-retake-play-and-use-video-screen-uiimagepickercontroller)

Another way is to use AVFoundation and we have an example from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score -4):

yes you can eliminate that step.

set UIImagePickerController property "allowsEditing" = NO

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have the line:
     imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

And it still forces me to choose whether to use or retake.

Comment: this doesn't bypass the "Retake/Use" Screen

Comment: it's only hide all controls from camera preview, and hide camera capture button too